# How to get workflow instance in an activity?

Tags: c#, workflow, workflow-foundation, workflow-activity

I was not able get the workflow instance in code activity of my workflow.how do I get it? I did check [WorkflowEventArgs.WorkflowInstance Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.workflow.runtime.workfloweventargs.workflowinstance.aspx) but in my code activity i do not have **WorkflowEventArgs**. instead i have **EventArgs**.

**What I am trying to do:**

basically, i need to access the Workflow queue data to get the values in queue. in the above url, the code is for the same but, its not in a code activity? what is the correct way to access the queue?

Answer (score 2):

From [Getting Your Workflow Instance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tilovell/archive/2010/02/26/getting-your-workflow-instance.aspx):

```
public sealed class LogState : CodeActivity
{
    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {
        Guid instanceId = context.WorkflowInstanceId;
        var connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"];


        WorkflowInstanceProxy proxy = context.GetExtension<WorkflowInstanceInfo>().GetProxy();
        //...
    }

    protected override void CacheMetadata(CodeActivityMetadata metadata)
    {
        base.CacheMetadata(metadata);
        metadata.AddDefaultExtensionProvider<WorkflowInstanceInfo>(() => new WorkflowInstanceInfo());
    }

    public class WorkflowInstanceInfo : IWorkflowInstanceExtension
    {
        WorkflowInstanceProxy proxy;

        public IEnumerable<object> GetAdditionalExtensions()
        {
            yield break;
        }

        public void SetInstance(WorkflowInstanceProxy instance)
        {

            this.proxy = instance;
        }

        public WorkflowInstanceProxy GetProxy() { return proxy; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused by your question.  Is this what you want?

```
public sealed class GetWorkflowIdActivity : CodeActivity<string>
{
    protected override string Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {
        return context.WorkflowInstanceId.ToString();
    }
}
```